# How do I "clear" an External SMR WD Drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have an external hard drive (WD My Passport, USB-C) which is SMR. I have filled it up and now writing any large amount of data results in massive slowdowns. How can I wipe this drive and start as new? Note: I cannot send TRIM commands to the device, since I am on a Mac/Windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use WD Discovery ([Mac](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=294&lang=en), [Windows](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=293&lang=en) specific download links since I cannot find the generic webpage) to password-lock the drive. Once this is done, there should be an option to either unlock the drive, or erase the drive. Erasing the drive will tell the drive to clear its DM-SMR config, meaning the drive no longer slowed down by continuous SMR management while attempting to write to the disk.